# Dbeaver - как скрыть другие базы данных в подключение?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Версия Dbeaver 7.2.1
Подключаюсь под `root` пользователем, соответственно отображаются все базы дынных в подключение.
Хочу скрыть остальные базы данных и работать только с одной конкретной.
Как это можно сделать?

[image: скрин01]

[image: скрин02]

Answer (score 1):

День добрый. В DBeaver есть возможность фильтровать базы данных.
Для этого надо зайти в настройки соединения и найти раздел "Общее" слева.

[image: фильтрация1]

Далее выбрать раздел фильтрации по базам и в новом окне ввести имя нужной Вам базы.

[image: фильтрация2]

[image: фильтрация3]

Снять фильтрацию можно в том же диалоге или кликнуть на вкладку "Базы данных" в дереве навигации слева.